# Perform token replacements using VS post-build event command?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I would like to "post-process" my app.config file and perform some token replacements after the project builds.

Is there an *easy* way to do this using a [VS post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(VS.80).aspx) command?

*(Yeah I know I could probably use NAnt or something, looking for something simple.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [XmlPreProcess](http://xmlpreprocess.sourceforge.net/). We use it for producing different config files for our testing and live deployment packages. 
We execute it from a nant script as part of a continuous build but, since it's a console app, I see no reason why you coudn't add a call in your project's post-build event instead